# JSON isn't binding to my model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

jQuery:

```
var mmr = new Mmr.FormData().mmr;
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "/Property/Mmr/Submit",
        data: JSON.stringify(mmr),
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        error: function () {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Submit(MonthlyMarketingReport report)
{
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

report is all empty data. I'm not sure why.

This is the json that gets posted... (Which is from a TypeScript class that gets converted from the c# model so this should be correct...)

```
{
    "RecentSale1": {
        "Street": "123",
        "City": "123123",
        "State": "CA",
        "Zip": "12313",
        "SaleDate": "08/07/2013",
        "Condition": "Fair",
        "SqFt": "213",
        "Bedrooms": "2",
        "Baths": "2",
        "Parking": "Drvwy",
        "Yearbuilt": "2",
        "DaysOnMarket": "2",
        "ListDate": "3",
        "SalePrice": "123",
        "Comments": "123"
    },
    "RecentSale2": {
        "Street": "123123",
        "City": "123123",
        "State": "FL",
        "Zip": "12343",
        "SaleDate": "08/07/2013",
        "Condition": "Fair",
        "SqFt": "123",
        "Bedrooms": "2",
        "Baths": "2",
        "Parking": "Attch3",
        "Yearbuilt": "1234",
        "DaysOnMarket": "3",
        "ListDate": "123",
        "SalePrice": "123",
        "Comments": "asfasdf"
    },
    "RecentSale3": {
        "Street": "13123",
        "City": "123",
        "State": "AK",
        "Zip": "12313",
        "SaleDate": "08/09/2013",
        "Condition": "Avg",
        "SqFt": "123",
        "Bedrooms": "1",
        "Baths": "12",
        "Parking": "Drvwy",
        "Yearbuilt": "123",
        "DaysOnMarket": "123",
        "ListDate": "123",
        "SalePrice": "123123",
        "Comments": "123123123"
    },
    "CurrentListing1": {
        "Street": "123",
        "City": "123",
        "State": "AZ",
        "Zip": "12323",
        "ListDate": "08/01/2013",
        "Condition": "Poor",
        "SqFt": "12312",
        "Bedrooms": "12",
        "Baths": "2",
        "Parking": "Asgn",
        "Yearbuilt": "123",
        "DaysOnMarket": "123",
        "CurrentListPrice": "123",
        "OriginalListPrice": "123123",
        "Comments": "123123"
    },
    "CurrentListing2": {
        "Street": "123",
        "City": "123",
        "State": "AZ",
        "Zip": "123",
        "ListDate": "08/13/2013",
        "Condition": "Fair",
        "SqFt": "123",
        "Bedrooms": "12",
        "Baths": "2",
        "Parking": "Asgn",
        "Yearbuilt": "123",
        "DaysOnMarket": "23",
        "CurrentListPrice": "23",
        "OriginalListPrice": "3123",
        "Comments": "123123123"
    },
    "CurrentListing3": {
        "Street": "2",
        "City": "323",
        "State": "AK",
        "Zip": "12312",
        "ListDate": "08/09/2013",
        "Condition": "Good",
        "SqFt": "123",
        "Bedrooms": "2",
        "Baths": "1",
        "Parking": "Asgn",
        "Yearbuilt": "3213",
        "DaysOnMarket": "123",
        "CurrentListPrice": "123123",
        "OriginalListPrice": "213123",
        "Comments": "123123123123213"
    },
    "LocalListingsCount": "234",
    "LocalDaysOnMarketAverage": "234",
    "LocalPriceLow": "23423",
    "LocalPriceHigh": "4234234",
    "LocalCompetition": "Decreasing",
    "LocalCondition": "Interior",
    "LocalPriceRange": "Interior",
    "Showings": "123",
    "ShowingsTotal": "123",
    "TourDateLast": "08/08/2013",
    "OpenHouseDateLast": "08/05/2013",
    "CommentsBuyerPositive": "dsfsd",
    "CommentsBuyerNegative": "sdfsd",
    "IsRepairsRecomended": true,
    "IsRepairsReccomendedExplain": "fsdfs",
    "IsRepairsEstimate": "123",
    "IsFinanced": false,
    "IsFinancedExplain": "sdfsd",
    "NotSoldExplain": "sdfsdf",
    "IsMarketedWhileOccupied": true,
    "IsMarketedWhileOccupiedExplain": "sdafsdf",
    "IsCodeViolation": true,
    "IsCodeViolationExplain": "sdf",
    "IsForSaleSign": false,
    "IsForSaleSignExplain": "123123",
    "IsClean": false,
    "IsCleanExplain": "fsdfsd",
    "IsTrashout": false,
    "IsTrashoutExplain": "adsfasdf",
    "IsUtilitiesOn": false,
    "IsUtilitiesOnExplain": "f",
    "IsWinterized": false,
    "IsWinterizedExplain": "sdfsdf",
    "IsHazard": true,
    "IsHazardExplain": "dfsdf",
    "IsRepairsCompleted": false,
    "IsRepairsCompletedExplain": "sdfsd",
    "IsVandalized": true,
    "IsInsuranceClaim": true,
    "CurrentCondition": "fsdfsdfdsfsdf",
    "MarketingStrategy": "asdfsdfsdf",
    "PriceRecommended": ""
}
```

My MonthlyMarketingReport class

```
public partial class MonthlyMarketingReport : Reports
{
    public Nullable<int> MarketingPlanId { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarketedWhileOccupied { get; set; }
    public string IsMarketedWhileOccupiedExplain { get; set; }
    public bool IsCodeViolation { get; set; }
    public string IsCodeViolationExplain { get; set; }
    public bool IsForSaleSign { get; set; }
    public string IsForSaleSignExplain { get; set; }
    public bool IsClean { get; set; }
    public string IsCleanExplain { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrashout { get; set; }
    public string IsTrashoutExplain { get; set; }
    public bool IsUtilitiesOn { get; set; }
    public string IsUtilitiesOnExplain { get; set; }
    public bool IsWinterized { get; set; }
    public string IsWinterizedExplain { get; set; }
    public bool IsHazard { get; set; }
    public string IsHazardExplain { get; set; }
    public bool IsRepairsCompleted { get; set; }
    public string IsRepairsCompletedExplain { get; set; }
    public bool IsVandalized { get; set; }
    public bool IsInsuranceClaim { get; set; }
    public string CurrentCondition { get; set; }
    public int Showings { get; set; }
    public int ShowingsTotal { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TourDateLast { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OpenHouseDateLast { get; set; }
    public string CommentsBuyerPositive { get; set; }
    public string CommentsBuyerNegative { get; set; }
    public bool IsRepairsRecomended { get; set; }
    public string IsRepairsReccomendedExplain { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> IsRepairsEstimate { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinanced { get; set; }
    public string IsFinancedExplain { get; set; }
    public string NotSoldExplain { get; set; }
    public int LocalListingsCount { get; set; }
    public int LocalDaysOnMarketAverage { get; set; }
    public decimal LocalPriceLow { get; set; }
    public decimal LocalPriceHigh { get; set; }
    public string LocalCompetition { get; set; }
    public string LocalCondition { get; set; }
    public string LocalPriceRange { get; set; }
    public string MarketingStrategy { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceRecommended { get; set; }
    public int CompIdRecentSale1 { get; set; }
    public int CompIdRecentSale2 { get; set; }
    public int CompIdRecentSale3 { get; set; }
    public int CompIdCurrentListing1 { get; set; }
    public int CompIdCurrentListing2 { get; set; }
    public int CompIdCurrentListing3 { get; set; }

    public virtual Comparables RecentSale1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Comparables RecentSale2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Comparables RecentSale3 { get; set; }
    public virtual Comparables CurrentListing1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Comparables CurrentListing2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Comparables CurrentListing3 { get; set; }
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your `MonthlyMarketingReport` class code.

Comment: Have you checked in fiddler or in a web debugger that you API url is good, aka you aren't getting a 404 error calling /Property/Mmr/Submit?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Sorry about that, added now.

Comment: @Brian The URL is OK because it enters the controller, just the model is empty and has no data in it.

Comment: Can we see your view, are you defining a model in your view?

Comment: Try changing `data: JSON.stringify(mmr),` to `mmr`.  Just send the object.  You're sending a single string.

Comment: @Brian I'm not using the model in the view with razor or anything, I'm just manually filling out the javascript object. it appears to get the data since the json that is listed in the answer is sent according to chrome dev tools.

Comment: @Amy I tried just mmr, and then it doesn't enter the controller at all, which I'm not quite sure I understand why either..

Comment: @user1308743 `method: "POST"` should be `type: "POST",`

Comment: If this is MVC (not the API), why is your method not returning an [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.108).aspx)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips No particular reason, I'm just testing it at the moment. It is regular MVC and not Web API. I don't believe the return type should have any effect to this, right?

Comment: @sza It is using POST according to dev tools so I don't think it was an issue, but I have type: "POST" a shot without success.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your controller action method is

```
public string Submit(MonthlyMarketingReport report)
```

So I think in your ajax call it should be

```
data: JSON.stringify({ report: mmr }),
```

Comment: I tried this out without success, it did not enter the controller at all this way, sadly =/.